# urllib.urlencode doesn't like unicode values: how about this workaround?

Tags: python, unicode, urlencode

If I have an object like:

```
d = {'a':1, 'en': 'hello'}
```

...then I can pass it to `urllib.urlencode`, no problem:

```
percent_escaped = urlencode(d)
print percent_escaped
```

But if I try to pass an object with a value of type `unicode`, game over:

```
d2 = {'a':1, 'en': 'hello', 'pt': u'olá'}
percent_escaped = urlencode(d2)
print percent_escaped # This fails with a UnicodeEncodingError
```

So my question is about a reliable way to prepare an object to be passed to `urlencode`.

I came up with this function where I simply iterate through the object and encode values of type string or unicode:

```
def encode_object(object):
  for k,v in object.items():
    if type(v) in (str, unicode):
      object[k] = v.encode('utf-8')
  return object
```

This seems to work:

```
d2 = {'a':1, 'en': 'hello', 'pt': u'olá'}
percent_escaped = urlencode(encode_object(d2))
print percent_escaped
```

And that outputs `a=1&en=hello&pt=%C3%B3la`, ready for passing to a POST call or whatever.

But my `encode_object` function just looks really shaky to me. For one thing, it doesn't handle nested objects.

For another, I'm nervous about that if statement. Are there any other types that I should be taking into account?

And is comparing the `type()` of something to the native object like this good practice?

```
type(v) in (str, unicode) # not so sure about this...
```

Thanks!

Comment: it should be `u'olá'` instead of `u'óla'`...

Comment: `PortugueseEncodingError`, sorry :)

Comment: just a thought on your last sentence: it should be `if isinstance(v, unicode)` rather than `if type(v) in ...`, also no need to match str as it does not need encoding

Comment: thanks, incorporated your suggestions.

Comment: I would sarcastically answer `sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")` but I'm afraid I'd lose all my rep and have my python badge revoked.

Comment: For me this needs to solved in the python docs. I created an issue: http://bugs.python.org/issue26433

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You should indeed be nervous. The whole idea that you might have a mixture of bytes and text in some data structure is horrifying. It violates the fundamental principle of working with string data: decode at input time, work exclusively in unicode, encode at output time.

Update in response to comment:

You are about to output some sort of HTTP request. This needs to be prepared as a byte string. The fact that urllib.urlencode is not capable of properly preparing that byte string if there are unicode characters with ordinal >= 128 in your dict is indeed unfortunate. If you have a mixture of byte strings and unicode strings in your dict, you need to be careful. Let's examine just what urlencode() does:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> tests = ['\x80', '\xe2\x82\xac', 1, '1', u'1', u'\x80', u'\u20ac']
>>> for test in tests:
...     print repr(test), repr(urllib.urlencode({'a':test}))
...
'\x80' 'a=%80'
'\xe2\x82\xac' 'a=%E2%82%AC'
1 'a=1'
'1' 'a=1'
u'1' 'a=1'
u'\x80'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 1282, in urlencode
    v = quote_plus(str(v))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x80' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The last two tests demonstrate the problem with urlencode(). Now let's look at the str tests.

If you insist on having a mixture, then you should at the very least ensure that the str objects are encoded in UTF-8.

'\x80' is suspicious -- it is not the result of any_valid_unicode_string.encode('utf8').
'\xe2\x82\xac' is OK; it's the result of u'\u20ac'.encode('utf8').
'1' is OK -- all ASCII characters are OK on input to urlencode(), which will percent-encode such as '%' if necessary.

Here's a suggested converter function. It doesn't mutate the input dict as well as returning it (as yours does); it returns a new dict. It forces an exception if a value is a str object but is not a valid UTF-8 string. By the way, your concern about it not handling nested objects is a little misdirected -- your code works only with dicts, and the concept of nested dicts doesn't really fly.

```
def encoded_dict(in_dict):
    out_dict = {}
    for k, v in in_dict.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, unicode):
            v = v.encode('utf8')
        elif isinstance(v, str):
            # Must be encoded in UTF-8
            v.decode('utf8')
        out_dict[k] = v
    return out_dict
```

and here's the output, using the same tests in reverse order (because the nasty one is at the front this time):

```
>>> for test in tests[::-1]:
...     print repr(test), repr(urllib.urlencode(encoded_dict({'a':test})))
...
u'\u20ac' 'a=%E2%82%AC'
u'\x80' 'a=%C2%80'
u'1' 'a=1'
'1' 'a=1'
1 'a=1'
'\xe2\x82\xac' 'a=%E2%82%AC'
'\x80'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in encoded_dict
  File "C:\python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
>>>
```

Does that help?

Comment: I don't get this part: if v is str (not unicode), then you do v.decode('utf8'). The result is a nice unicode string. But exactly this is not supported by `urlencode()`. Can you understand my concern? ... Ah, you even drop the return value. This is like an assert statement ... maybe.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem with German "Umlaute".
The solution is pretty simple:

In Python 3+, urlencode allows to specify the encoding:

```
from urllib import urlencode
args = {}
args = {'a':1, 'en': 'hello', 'pt': u'olá'}
urlencode(args, 'utf-8')

>>> 'a=1&en=hello&pt=ol%3F'
```

Comment: Thank you!
Yes that solution works for me too and is clearly much simpler than all other solutions here.

Comment: Watch out!  In python 2, the optional second arg to `urlencode` is `doseq`. There is no `encoding` arg in python 2.7 at all, but there is in python 3.

Answer (score 7):

Seems like it is a wider topic than it looks, especially when you have to deal with more complex dictionary values. I found 3 ways of solving the problem:

1. Patch urllib.py to include encoding parameter:

   ```
   def urlencode(query, doseq=0, encoding='ascii'):
   ```

   and replace all `str(v)` conversions to something like `v.encode(encoding)`

   Obviously not good, since it's hardly redistributable and even harder to maintain.
2. Change default Python encoding as described [here](http://www.ianbicking.org/illusive-setdefaultencoding.html). The author of the blog pretty clearly describes some problems with this solution and who knows how more of them could be lurking in the shadows. So it doesn't look good to me either.
3. So I, personally, ended up with this abomination, which encodes all unicode strings to UTF-8 byte strings in any (reasonably) complex structure:

   ```
   def encode_obj(in_obj):

       def encode_list(in_list):
           out_list = []
           for el in in_list:
               out_list.append(encode_obj(el))
           return out_list

       def encode_dict(in_dict):
           out_dict = {}
           for k, v in in_dict.iteritems():
               out_dict[k] = encode_obj(v)
           return out_dict

       if isinstance(in_obj, unicode):
           return in_obj.encode('utf-8')
       elif isinstance(in_obj, list):
           return encode_list(in_obj)
       elif isinstance(in_obj, tuple):
           return tuple(encode_list(in_obj))
       elif isinstance(in_obj, dict):
           return encode_dict(in_obj)

       return in_obj
   ```

   You can use it like this: `urllib.urlencode(encode_obj(complex_dictionary))`

   To encode keys also, `out_dict[k]` can be replaced with `out_dict[k.encode('utf-8')]`, but it was a bit too much for me.

Comment: thank you for this answer. I think this should be solved in the python docs: http://bugs.python.org/issue26433

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you can't pass a Unicode object to urlencode, so, before calling it, you should encode every unicode object parameter. How you do this in a proper way seems to me very dependent on the context, but in your code you should always be aware of when to use the unicode python object (the unicode representation) and when to use the encoded object (bytestring).

Also, encoding the str values is "superfluous": [What is the difference between encode/decode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447107/whats-the-difference-between-encode-decode-python-2-x/449281#449281)

Comment: @pat, @Javier: encoding the str values might be superfluous, but it does at least flush out str values that are not decodable as UTF-8. Try `'\x80'.encode('utf8')` to see what I mean. Doing nothing instead leaves you exposed to error. You should explicitly check your str values -- see my updated answer.

Comment: @John: I agree with explicitly checking that the str values are decodable in the encoding you're working with (UTF-8 in this case). However, I think that you should test that using decode (as you proposed in your solution) to unambiguously express the intended behavior. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing new to add except to point out that the urlencode algorithm is nothing tricky.
Rather than processing your data once and then calling urlencode on it, it would be perfectly fine to do something like:

```
from urllib import quote_plus

def urlencode_utf8(params):
    if hasattr(params, 'items'):
        params = params.items()
    return '&'.join(
        (quote_plus(k.encode('utf8'), safe='/') + '=' + quote_plus(v.encode('utf8'), safe='/')
            for k, v in params))
```

Looking at the source code for the urllib module (Python 2.6), their implementation does not do much more. There is an optional feature where values in the parameters that are themselves 2-tuples are turned into separate key-value pairs, which is sometimes useful, but if you know you won't need that, the above will do.

You can even get rid of the `if hasattr('items', params):` if you know you won't need to handle lists of 2-tuples as well as dicts.

Comment: That might fail with `'float' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this `add_get_to_url()` method:

```
import urllib

def add_get_to_url(url, get):
   return '%s?%s' % (url, urllib.urlencode(list(encode_dict_to_bytes(get))))

def encode_dict_to_bytes(query):
    if hasattr(query, 'items'):
        query=query.items()
    for key, value in query:
        yield (encode_value_to_bytes(key), encode_value_to_bytes(value))

def encode_value_to_bytes(value):
    if not isinstance(value, unicode):
        return str(value)
    return value.encode('utf8')
```

Features:

- "get" can be a dict or a list of (key, value) pairs
- Order is not lost
- values can be integers or other simple datatypes.

Feedback welcome.

Answer (score -1):

this one line working fine in my case -->

```
urllib.quote(unicode_string.encode('utf-8'))
```

thanks @IanCleland and @PavelVlasov

Answer (score -4):

Why so long answers?

`urlencode(unicode_string.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: Perhaps you mean `urllib.quote`? `urlencode` takes a sequence or dict, not a string.

Comment: this one line working fine in my case 

urllib.quote(unicode_string.encode('utf-8'))