# URLEncoding from a string

Tags: python

I am familiar with `urlencode`, which encodes a dictionary of parameters. How would I encode a string such as the following to a url-safe string?

```
s =     'http://google.com/search?q=' 
     +  'パイレーツ・オブ・カリビアン／呪われた海賊たち（日本語吹替版）' 
     + ' ' 
     + 'site:imdb.com/title'

urlencoded_str = ?
```

Comment: What do you mean by url-safe string? Most browsers, i.e. non-internet explorer, support unicode in urls :)

Comment: Well, the parentheticals and such wouldn't be interpreted correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695183/how-to-percent-encode-url-parameters-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility (the encoding line is to tell Python the encoding of the file):

```
# vim: encoding=utf-8

import urllib

base_url = 'http://google.com/search'
params = dict(
    q=('パイレーツ・オブ・カリビアン／呪われた海賊たち（日本語吹替版）'
       + ' site:imdb.com/title'))

query = urllib.urlencode(params)
print base_url + '?' + query
```

For better solutions look at this question: [urllib.urlencode doesn't like unicode values: how about this workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480723/urllib-urlencode-doesnt-like-unicode-values-how-about-this-workaround)

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you want to achive, but maybe something like this:

```
#!coding: utf-8
from urllib import quote

s = 'http://google.com/search?q={}site:wikipedia.org'

escape_me = 'パイレーツ・オブ・カリビアン／呪われた海賊たち（日本語吹替版） '

urlencoded_str = s.format(quote(escape_me))
```