# what's the difference between unicode(self) and self.__unicode__() in a Python Class?

Tags: python, class, unicode, python-2.x

while handling unicode problem, I found that `unicode(self)` and `self.__unicode__()` have different behaviour:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import sys
import dis
class test():
    def __unicode__(self):
        s = u'中文'
        return s.encode('utf-8')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__unicode__()
print dis.dis(test)
a = test()
print a
```

the above code works okay, but if I change `self.__unicode__()` to `unicode(self)`, it will show error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

the code with problem is:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import sys
import dis
class test():
    def __unicode__(self):
        s = u'中文'
        return s.encode('utf-8')

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self)
print dis.dis(test)
a = test()
print a
```

very curious about how python handle this, I tried dis module but didn't see too many difference:

```
Disassembly of __str__:
 12           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (__unicode__)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

**VS**

```
Disassembly of __str__:
 10           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (unicode)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Hm, two versions of code you mentioned are the same...

Comment: sorry, first should be self.__unicode__(). I have changed it.

Comment: Why would you return *encoded* bytes from a unicode method? Don't do that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = u'中文'
return s.encode('utf-8')
```

This returns a non-Unicode, byte string. That's what `encode` is doing. utf-8 is not a thing that magically turns data into Unicode; if anything, it's the opposite - a way of representing Unicode (an abstraction) in bytes (data, more or less).

We need a bit of terminology here. To **encode** is to take a Unicode string and making a byte string that *represents* it, using some kind of encoding. To **decode** is the reverse: taking a byte string (that we think encodes a Unicode string), and *interpreting* it as a Unicode string, using a specified encoding.

When we encode to a byte string and then decode using the same encoding, we get the original Unicode back.

`utf-8` is one possible encoding. There are many, many more.

Sometimes Python will report a `UnicodeDecodeError` when you call `encode`. Why? Because you try to `encode` a byte string. The proper input for this process is a Unicode string, so Python "helpfully" tries to `decode` the byte string to Unicode first. But it doesn't know what codec to use, so it assumes `ascii`. This codec is the safest choice, in an environment where you could receive all kinds of data. It simply reports an error for bytes >= 128, which are handled in a gazillion different ways in various 8-bit encodings. (Remember trying to import a Word file with letters like `é` from a Mac to a PC or vice-versa, way back in the day? You'd get some other weird symbol on the other computer, because the platform built-in encoding was different.)

Making things even more complicated, in Python 2 the `encode`/`decode` mechanism is also used to implement some other neat things that have nothing to do with interpreting Unicode. For example, there is a Base64 encoder, and a thing that automatically handles string escape sequences (i.e. it will change a backslash, followed by a letter 't', into a tab). Some of these **do** "encode" or "decode" from a byte string to a byte string, or from Unicode to Unicode.

(**By the way, this all works completely differently - much more clearly, IMHO - in Python 3.**)

Similarly, when `__unicode__` returns a byte string (which it **should not**, as a matter of style), the Python `unicode()` built-in function automatically decodes it as `ascii`; and when `__str__` returns a Unicode string (which again it **should not**), `str()` will encode it as `ascii`. This happens behind the scenes, in code you cannot control. However, you can fix `__unicode__` and `__str__` to do what they are supposed to do.

(You can, in fact, override the encoding for `unicode`, by passing a second parameter. However, this is the wrong solution here since you should already have a Unicode string returned from `__unicode__`. And `str` doesn't take an encoding parameter, so you're out of luck there.)

So, now we can solve the problem.

Problem: We want `__unicode__` to return the Unicode string `u'中文'`, and we want `__str__` to return the `utf-8`-encoded version of that.

Solution: return that string directly in `__unicode__`, and do the encoding explicitly in `__str__`:

```
class test():
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'中文'

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Great explanation. Another way of putting it: Unicode is not an encoding.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447107/whats-the-difference-between-encode-decode-python-2-x/448383#448383

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation! I may misunderstanded about how the overriding works. I always thought that call str(obj) is the same with call obj.__str__().   and unicode(obj) should be the same with obj.__unicode__(). but I guess using str(obj), unicode(obj), the system built-in function did some other stuff first, then pass the control to overriding method such as `__str__` and `__unicode__`, is that right?

Answer (score 5):

You return `bytes` from your `__unicode__` method.

To make it clear:

```
In [18]: class Test(object):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'äö↓'.encode('utf-8')
    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self)
   ....:     

In [19]: class Test2(object):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'äö↓'
    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self)
   ....:     

In [20]: t = Test()

In [21]: t.__str__()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/dav1d/<ipython-input-21-e2650f29e6ea> in <module>()
----> 1 t.__str__()

/home/dav1d/<ipython-input-18-8bc639cbc442> in __str__(self)
      3         return u'äö↓'.encode('utf-8')
      4     def __str__(self):
----> 5         return unicode(self)
      6 

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

In [22]: unicode(t)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/dav1d/<ipython-input-22-716c041af66e> in <module>()
----> 1 unicode(t)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

In [23]: t2 = Test2()

In [24]: t2.__str__()
Out[24]: u'\xe4\xf6\u2193'

In [25]: str(_) # _ = last result
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/dav1d/<ipython-input-25-3a1a0b74e31d> in <module>()
----> 1 str(_) # _ = last result

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)'

In [26]: unicode(t2)
Out[26]: u'\xe4\xf6\u2193'

In [27]: class Test3(object):
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'äö↓'
def __str__(self):
    return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')
....:     

In [28]: t3 = Test3()

In [29]: t3.__unicode__()
Out[29]: u'\xe4\xf6\u2193'

In [30]: t3.__str__()
Out[30]: '\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xe2\x86\x93'

In [31]: print t3
äö↓

In [32]: print unicode(t3)
äö↓
```

`print a` or in my case `print t` will call `t.__str__` which es expected to return `bytes` you let it return `unicode` so it tries to encode it with `ascii` which will not work.

Easy fix: let `__unicode__` return unicode and `__str__` bytes.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `unicode` on a Python object, the output is the unicode representation of the argument you pass to the `unicode` method.

Since you haven't specified what encoding should be used, you get an error that the argument can't be represented using only ASCII.

When you use `__unicode__` you're specifying that utf-8 should be used to encode that string, which is correct and happens with no problems.

You can use the desired encoding as a second parameter to the `unicode` method, such as:

```
unicode( str, "utf-8" )
```

And that should work the same way that your `__unicode__` method does.

Answer (score 0):

When you defined the `__unicode__` special method you told it what encoding to use. When you simply call `unicode` you did not specify the encoding, so Python used the default "ascii".

BTW, `__str__` should return a string of bytes, not unicode. and `__unicode__` should return unicode, not a byte string. So this code is backwards. Since it's not returning a unicode Python is probably trying to convert it using the default encoding.