# Difference between Unicode and decoded strings

Tags: perl, unicode, decode

Are `decoded strings` without additional attributes and `Unicode` interchangeable?

Update:

Does it make a difference if I write

```
subroutine expects decoded strings.
```

or write

```
subroutine expects Unicode strings.
```

?

```
sub subroutine {
    my $unicode = shift;
    utf8::upgrade( $unicode );
    my $gcs = Unicode::GCString->new( $unicode );
    my $colwidth = $gcs->columns();
    return $colwidth;
}
```

Comment: Get this one, you will find it   
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447107/whats-the-difference-between-encode-decode-python-2-x

Comment: @Pir Fahim Shah, That linked node is not relevant. sid_com didn't ask what happens when one decodes something that's already been decoded. And even if he did, the answer for Perl5 is different than the answer for Python.

Comment: what do you *mean*?  what do you want to *do*?  contextless use of terms like this isn't going to get you any kind of meaningful answer IMO

Comment: I want to check if my understanding makes sense. I would not say contextless - the tags for example are some kind of context.

Comment: sid_com: what is a "decoded string"? what is "Unicode"?  (the latter has a precise definition, but it's pretty clear that's not what you mean; people use the term to mean all kinds of things.)  How about a sample script with a question about what it does?  If you can't reduce your question to that, you probably have more than one question.

Comment: @ysth, I assumed they meant "string produced by `decode`" and "string of Unicode code points", and gave my answer in those terms. If he meant something else, he can elaborate.

Comment: the edited question is much more answerable, thanks; @ikegami, you want to take a swing at it?

Comment: @ysth, All I got is: I suspect more people will understand if you say "decoded" instead of "Unicode", but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are talking about decoding a character encoding (UTF-8, cp1252, etc), yes.

Encode's `decode` produces a string of Unicode code points. "Unicode string" is a fitting description of the result.

Note that "Unicode string" is not an fitting alternative to "strings stored using the UTF8=1 format". Unlike the strings returned by `decode`, a string stored using the UTF8=1 format is not necessarily a string of Unicode code points.

Comment: The perl documentation I find states that decode converts encoded strings into Perl's internal format. I can't find anything that specifies what that is. Are you sure it's not UTF-16, which would mean  not all codepoints are represented directly by their own value?

Comment: neither one of those sounds like strings of unicode codepoints. They both sound like strings of 8-bit code units (UTF-8 uses 8-bit code units).

Comment: Since his question is about the result of decode, and the result of decode is a string in Perl's internal format, I took his question to be "Is Perl's internal format interchangeable with `Unicode`?" Maybe that's wrong though.

Comment: @bames53, By the way, I added to my answer to avoid any confusion.