# How to compare unicode and str in Python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, ascii, gbk

My code:

```
a = '汉'
b = u'汉'
```

These two are the same Chinese character. But obviously, `a == b` is `False`. How do I fix this? Note, I can't convert `a` to `utf-8` because I have no access to the code. I need to convert `b` to the encoding that `a` is using.

So, my question is, what do I do to turn the encoding of `b` into that of `a`?

Comment: Read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html (the first people to answer bellow probably should take a read as well - they seen to have more guessed ways to make it work than properly understand what is going on)

Comment: I know what unicode is. I just need to know, *in Python*, what can I do to turn `b` into the same encoding as `a`, so that they can be compared.

Comment: read the article. you won't regret.

Comment: @SMTNinja If one of the answers below helped you with your question, consider marking it correct so the question will close.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know `a`'s encoding, you'll need to:

1. detect `a`'s encoding
2. encode `b` using the detected encoding

First, to detect `a`'s encoding, let's use [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet).

```
$ pip install chardet
```

Now let's use it:

```
>>> import chardet
>>> a = '汉'
>>> chardet.detect(a)
{'confidence': 0.505, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
```

So, to actually accomplish what you requested:

```
>>> encoding = chardet.detect(a)['encoding']
>>> b = u'汉'
>>> b_encoded = b.encode(encoding)
>>> a == b_encoded
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Decode the encoded string `a` using [`str.decode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.decode):

```
>>> a = '汉'
>>> b = u'汉'
>>> a.decode('utf-8') == b
True
```

**NOTE** Replace `utf-8` according to the source code encoding.

Comment: The correct thing to do is to _encode_ the non unicode text, and compare both in unicode space, not the oposite.

Comment: @jsbueno, Do you mean *decode* the non unicode text?

Comment: @jsbueno, I updated the answer according to your comment. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score -1):

both `a.decode` and `b.encode` are OK:

```
In [133]: a.decode('utf') == b
Out[133]: True

In [134]: b.encode('utf') == a
Out[134]: True
```

Note that `str.encode` and `unicode.decode` are also available, don't mix them up. See *[What is the difference between encode/decode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447107/what-is-the-difference-between-encode-decode)*

Comment: -1 for suggesting random usage of "decode" and "encode". Please, read the link I posted in the comments of the question before trying to code any other thing that deals with text.