# encode and decode for a specific character set

Tags: python

There is no difference for the printing results, what is the usage of encoding and decoding for utf-8?
And is it encode('utf8') or encode('utf-8')?

```
u ='abc'
print(u)
u=u.encode('utf-8')
print(u)
uu = u.decode('utf-8')
print(uu)
```

Comment: Try running that in Python 2...

Comment: Obligatory link to the famous [what every programmer should know](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: @MattDMo it prints the exact same thing in Python 2 and 3

Comment: @NickT use the REPL, or `repr()` to see the difference. `str.decode()` produces a Unicode string, `str.encode()` does not. As it should...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.encode` encodes the string (or unicode string) into a series of bytes. In Python 3 this is a `bytearray`, in Python 2 it's `str` again (confusingly). When you encode a unicode string, you are left with bytes, *not* unicode—remember that *UTF-8 is not unicode*, it's an encoding method that can turn unicode codepoints into bytes.

`str.decode` will decode the serialized byte stream with the selected codec, picking the proper unicode codepoints and giving you a unicode string.

So, what you're doing in Python 2 is: `'abc'` > `'abc'` > `u'abc'`, and in Python 3 is:
`'abc'` > `b'abc'` > `'abc'`. Try printing `repr(u)` or `type(u)` in addition to see what's changing where.

[`utf_8` might be the most canonical](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings), but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Is it possible to look at the underlying byte array for the string in Python 2?

Comment: @william007 it would be implementation-specific; why--what are you trying to do? `bytearray` is a type that Python exposes to you, internally (in CPython) it's probably a `char` array. For a Python unicode string, it's stored as (again, in CPython) an array of [`Py_UNICODE` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/unicode.html#c.Py_UNICODE). They're fairly non-portable and meaningless outside of CPython.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Python will first try to decode it to unicode before it can encode it back to UTF-8.There are encording which doesnt have anything to do with the character sets which can be applied to 8 bit strings

For eg

```
data = u'\u00c3'            # Unicode data
 data = data.encode('utf8')
 print data

'\xc3\x83' //the output.
```

Please have a look through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447107/what-is-the-difference-between-encode-decode) and [here](http://www.evanjones.ca/python-utf8.html).It would be helpful.

Comment: In the example provided, the OP isn't decoding any unicode strings.