# Clear invalid escape in python?

Tags: python, string, escaping

In Python, I have a string:

```
a = "\s"
```

In JavaScript, `a` would be the single letter `"s"`, but in Python, `a` would be `"\s"`.

How can I make Python behave the same way as JavaScript in this situation?

---

the real case may be more complicate : `a = "<div class=\"haha\"><\/div>"` , In this case , JavaScript get right HTML but python failed

Comment: `a="s"`. There is some differences between languages. Your string is `\s` if you want an output like `s` then you have to change it. Otherwise I don't see anything wrong here. Or use regex .

Comment: Do you mean a = "<\div>"? (ack... you're editing while I ask, so feel free to ignore this)

Comment: This is just a language-based quirk. Don't use unintuitive escapes and you won't run into this problem. Your "real-case" demonstrates this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there are no encoding/decoding that is happening?

Is `a == r"\s"` ?

You could simply:

```
a.replace('\\','')
```

example:

```
>>> a = "<div class=\"haha\"><\/div>"
>>> a.replace('\\','')
'<div class="haha"></div>'
```

See:

- [What exactly do "u" and "r" string flags do in Python, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l)
- [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)
- [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python)
- [What is the difference between encode/decode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447107/what-is-the-difference-between-encode-decode)