# how to change jpg rating with python

Tags: python, image, encoding, image-manipulation, rating

### Why

i trained a Network to sort images due to my own taste and pass it to Lightroom, or more precise to the xmp file of the rated Picture. Since i mostly shoot in RAW Lightroom saves a xmp file for every picture. For my older pictures - shoot in jpg - i would like to do the same.

### Problem

I can't manage to edit the rating of jpgs without destroying it. The following three attempts are the most promising ones among many.

#### 1.

load the image with `open(filename, encoding="ANSI")`

```
def change_rating_jpg(filename):  
    f = open(filename,"r+", encoding='ANSI')
    d = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for i in d:
        if i != '   xmp:Rating="1"\n':
            f.write(i)
    f.truncate()
    f.close()
```

#### 2.

Then i wanted to edit the EXIF Data of the file, but there is no rating.

If interested in how to load EXIF:

```
img = Image.open(filepath)

import PIL.ExifTags
exif = {
    PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v
    for k, v in img._getexif().items()
    if k in PIL.ExifTags.TAGS
}
```

#### 3.

Afterwards i used [this attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30960499/8019270) but it didn't worked as well.

```
def change_rating_jpg(filename):
    image_handle = open(filename, 'rb')
    raw_image_data = image_handle.read()
    encoded_data = b64encode(raw_image_data)
    compressed_data = zlib.compress(encoded_data, 9) 
    uncompressed_data = zlib.decompress(compressed_data)
    decoded_data = b64decode(uncompressed_data)

    manipulated_data = decoded_data.replace(b'   xmp:Rating="1"\n', b"")

    new_image_handle = open('new_'+filename, 'wb')

    new_image_handle.write(manipulated_data)
    new_image_handle.close()
    image_handle.close()
```