# UnicodeEncodeError in BeautifulSoup webscraper

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup, encode

I'm having a unicode encode error with the following code for a simple web scraper.

```
print 'JSON scraper initializing'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import requests
import geocoder


# Set page variable
page = 'https://www.bandsintown.com/?came_from=257&page='
urlBucket = []
for i in range (1,3):
    uniqueUrl = page + str(i)
    urlBucket.append(uniqueUrl)

# Build response container
responseBucket = []

for i in urlBucket:
    uniqueResponse = requests.get(i)
    responseBucket.append(uniqueResponse)


# Build soup container
soupBucket = []
for i in responseBucket:
    individualSoup = BeautifulSoup(i.text, 'html.parser')
    soupBucket.append(individualSoup)


# Build events container
allSanFranciscoEvents = []
for i in soupBucket:
    script = i.find_all("script")[4]

    eventsJSON = json.loads(script.text)

    allSanFranciscoEvents.append(eventsJSON)


with open("allSanFranciscoEvents.json", "w") as writeJSON:
   json.dump(allSanFranciscoEvents, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)
print ('end')
```

The odd thing is the sometimes, this code works, and doesn't give an error.  It has to do with the `for i in range` line of the code.  For example, if I put in `(2,4)` for the range, it works fine.  If I change it to `1,3,` it reads:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue within my code?  If I print `allSanFranciscoEvents`, it is reading in all the data, so I believe the issue is happening in the final piece of code, with the JSON dump.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eventsJSON` is object it can't use `eventsJSON.encode('utf-8')`. For Python 2.7 to write the file in `utf-8` or unicode you can use `codecs` or write it using binary or `wb` flag.

```
with open("allSanFranciscoEvents.json", "wb") as writeJSON:
   jsStr = json.dumps(allSanFranciscoEvents)
   # the decode() needed because we need to convert it to binary
   writeJSON.write(jsStr.decode('utf-8')) 
print ('end')

# and read it normally
with open("allSanFranciscoEvents.json", "r") as readJson:
    data = json.load(readJson)
    print(data[0][0]["startDate"])
    # 2019-02-04
```

Comment: Ok.  But then, if I use: json.dump(unicode(allSanFranciscoEvents), writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)  How do I deal with those 'u tags?  Any way to easily remove them?

Comment: updated the answer, take a look. previous asnwer is not correct.

Comment: Thank you !  This is appearing to work now.  What made it finally work?  Was it the jsStr?  And what is the functional difference between 'encode' and 'decode'?

Comment: as I said above, writing file in unicode solve the problem. jsStr is converted json string from from object. and for that different read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447107/)

Answer (score 1):

**Best Fix**

Use Python 3! Python 2 is [going EOL](https://pythonclock.org/) very soon. New code written in legacy python today will have a very short shelf life.

The only thing I had to change to make your code work in python 3 was to call the `print()` function instead of the `print` keyword. Your example code then worked without any error.

**Persisting with Python 2**

> The odd thing is the sometimes, this code works, and doesn't give an
>   error. It has to do with the for i in range line of the code. For
>   example, if I put in (2,4) for the range, it works fine.

That is because you are requesting different pages with those different ranges, and not every page has a character that can't be converted to `str` using the ascii codec. I had to go to page 5 of the response to get the same error that you did. In my case, it was the artist name, `u'Mø'` that caused the issue. So here's a 1 liner that reproduces the issue:

```
>>> str(u'Mø')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf8' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Your error explicitly singles out the character `u'\xe9'`:

```
>>> str(u'\xe9')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Same issue, just different character. The character is [Latin small letter e with acute](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=U%2B00E9). Python is trying to use the default encoding, 'ascii', to convert the `Unicode` string to `str`, but 'ascii' doesn't know what the code point is.

> I believe the issue is happening in the final piece of code, with the
>   JSON dump.

Yes, it is:

```
>>> with open('tmp.json', 'w') as f:
...     json.dump(u'\xe9', f, ensure_ascii=False)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 190, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And from the traceback, you can see that it's actually coming from writing to the file (`fp.write(chunk)`).

[`file.write()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) writes a `string` to a file, but `u'\xe9'` is a `unicode` object. The error message: `'ascii' codec can't encode character...` tells us that python is trying to encode that `unicode` object to turn it into a `str` type, so it can write it to the file. Calling encode on the unicode string uses the ["default string encoding"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode), which is defined [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#encodings) to be 'ascii'.

To fix, don't leave it up to python to use the default encoding:

```
>>> with open('tmp.json', 'w') as f:
...     json.dump(u'\xe9'.encode('utf-8'), f, ensure_ascii=False)
...
# No error :)
```

In your specific example, you can fix the intermittent error by changing this:

```
allSanFranciscoEvents.append(eventsJSON)
```

to this:

```
allSanFranciscoEvents.append(eventsJSON.encode('utf-8'))
```

That way, you are explicitly using the 'utf-8' codec to convert the `Unicode` strings to `str`, so that python doesn't try to apply the default encoding, 'ascii' when writing to the file.

Comment: Thank you for the help, all.  I've tried both of these solutions but unfortunately I can't get either working 100%.  With this solution:  allSanFranciscoEvents.append(eventsJSON.encode('utf-8')) - if I put this line of code in the 'for i in soupBucket' loop, I get an error:  'list' object has no attribute 'encode'.   The first solution presented above -   json.dump(unicode(allSanFranciscoEvents), writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False) - works, but it embeds the 'u tag in all of my data, which is present even when I import the JSON into a javascript framework.  Any suggestions? Thanks again !

Comment: That's because in using the `unicode()` solution you are writing the `__repr__()` of the `Unicode` instance to the json file, which includes the prefix `'u'`. Your example above with the one-line change I note above works for me, so I can't help you any further.