# text column get truncated to 1 char when loading with csvkit to mssql

Tags: sql-server, csv

I am using **csvkit** (specifically, the [**csvsql**](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/scripts/csvsql.html) tool) to load a tab delimited file to an mssql db.
Numeric fields are processed correctly, while all the text (`varchar`) fields are loaded to the DB as a single character (their first one).

The column type according to `csvstat -c` is `'unicode'`. In the DB, I tried loading to a `varchar` and `nvarchar` field. Both showed the same phenomenon of loading just a single character.

I suspect it is related to **csvkit** or the file's encoding, because when I write a manual sql `INSERT` statement the value ends up in the DB correctly.

How can I fix it to load the field correctly?

Comment: Probably the column or the variable used to populated it is declared as [`nvarchar` with no length, which makes it an `nvarchar(1)`](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: Actually, I tried it with `varchar(2048)` & `nvarchar(2048)` with the same unsuccessful results.

Comment: **I suspect it is related to csvkit or the file's encoding** And what is the file's encoding?  And for what's it's worth, you have to know the file's encoding.  If you don't know the file's encoding, then you aren't going to be reading that file.

Comment: The csv file's encoding (according to 'enca' and 'uchardet' tools) is UTF-8. I added an explicit encoding specification to the 'csvsql' command line (using the '--encoding' option) but got the same result of 1-char long text fields after loading the data. Any more ideas? should the file's encoding match the db's encoding?