# How to check Unicode char in python

Tags: python, unicode

```
def order_check_uni(body):  
    ccnt=0  
    for x in body:    
        if x.isUpper():  
            ccnt+=1  
        if ccnt>2:  
            print 'success'
```

I try to find char non ASCII or special char or unicode char or cyrillic char like `абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя ®©™` in string body with that script, i try to replace `isUpper()` with `isascii()` and `len(x) == len(x.encode)`, with `unichr()` and the other function but still find error, can somebody help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string is unicode or ascii?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987327/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-unicode-or-ascii)

Comment: it can't i try but not working, just need the function to replace isUpper() or maybe with other way

Comment: did you try the code mentioned in the link that i have posted?

Comment: yes bro, but still find error. Have other suloution ?

Comment: can you upload the code you tried with the example inputs and the output / error you got?

Comment: example if i try to use  
    if not x in string.ascii_letters:  
that is only will execute all except alphabet ascii, but i want to execute all non ascii, not only alhabet in ascii.

Comment: @Ja8zyjits this question seems to be more about the nature of the codepoints in the string rather than the object type. The question you linked is *not* a duplicate.

Comment: @MarkRansom I read the question and tried to understand what he meant, but I guess I could not really interpret it properly. But then since it was about finding the special and unicode chars i googled and found out the answer did exist and i found the link. Even in a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004442/how-to-check-unicode-char-in-python?noredirect=1#comment51912667_32004828) here in an answer below the op did mention he needs to check if the character entered is a unicode or not. but may be I interpreted this wrong.

Answer (score 8):

```
for x in body:
    if ord(x) > 127:
        # character is *not* ASCII
```

This works if you have a Unicode string. If you just want to detect if the string *contains* a non-ASCII character it also works on a UTF-8 encoded byte string.

Update for Python 3: the above still works on Unicode strings, but `ord` no longer works for byte strings.  But that's OK, because indexing into a byte string already returns an integer - no conversion necessary!  The code becomes even simpler, especially if you combine it with the `any` function:

```
if any(x > 127 for x in body):
    # string is *not* ASCII
```

Answer (score 1):

Not Sure, whats your exact requirement is

```
>>> u'aあä'.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
'a'
```

I Found this at [Python: Convert Unicode to ASCII without errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365411/python-convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors)

Comment: he need to check whether the entered text is a unicode or not.

Comment: u'aあä'.encode('ascii', 'ignore').isupper()
This may the solve the problem

Comment: Ja8zyjits yes, that is what i want :D

Comment: The point is I need to check whether the entered text is a unicode or not.
Not to encode or decode.

Comment: if iam using isinstance(x, unicode) the ascii char will be executed too, im just want to find char non ascii brother

Answer (score -1):

you can chech if a string is unicode by using the method `isinstance()`

```
s = u'aあä'
if isinstance(s, unicode):
  do_something()
```