# Selecting columns that have accented names using cx_Oracle

Tags: sql, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I have a similar problem to the one that Didina Deen had more than 1 year ago ([Handling accents in Oracle from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975885/handling-accents-in-oracle-from-python/)). I need to obtain information from an Oracle table with column names that contain accents. The table has many columns, so I would like to filter in the query. Right now I have to do a 'Select *' and take the +100 columns, to take only the column that I need by specifying its position.

```
import cx_Oracle

my_query = "SELECT descripción_oferta FROM big_table WHERE IDENTIFICADOR = 'XXXXXX'"
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(oracle_host, oracle_port, service_name=oracle_servicename)
con = cx_Oracle.connect(oracle_user, oracle_password, dsn)
cur.execute(my_query)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' in position 180: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have access to the table for sure, I can select other columns that don't have accents, so it must be this. I have tried with 'utf-8', 'latin1', ... encodings, without success.

In case you wonder, I am not the great mind that had the idea of giving columns names with accents...

Comment: The OP in that question seem to have solved their problem, have you tried that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40016537/7998591

Comment: Where and how have you tried/specified 'utf-8' etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to deal with this is to specify the encoding when creating the connection, as follows:

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(oracle_user, oracle_password, dsn, encoding="UTF-8")
```

I just created a table with the same column name you specified and with encoding specified as noted above, it works fine. If not, you get the error you saw.