# Creating h2o dataframe from pandas and unicode error

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, unicode, h2o

How can I convert pandas object to h2o dataframe safely?

```
import h2o
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,1,2], 'col2': ['César Chávez Day', 'César Chávez Day', 'César Chávez Day']})
hf = h2o.H2OFrame(df)  #gives error
```

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in
>   position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

**Environment:** Python 3.5, h2o 3.10.4.2

Comment: you're steps are correct the error you are getting is unrelated to h2o, try look up the error message itself, or looking at this stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

Answer (score 7):

I agree that this is not an H2O-specific issue.  This works for me (same H2O and Python version):

```
import h2o
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,1,2], 'col2': ['César Chávez Day', 'César Chávez Day', 'César Chávez Day']})
hf = h2o.H2OFrame(df)

## -- End pasted text --
Parse progress: |█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100%

In [4]: hf
Out[4]:   col1  col2
------  ----------------
     1  César Chávez Day
     1  César Chávez Day
     2  César Chávez Day

[3 rows x 2 columns]

In [5]: type('César Chávez Day')
Out[5]: str
```

My specs (you may need to change your default encoding):

```
In [6]: import sys

In [7]: sys.getdefaultencoding()
Out[7]: 'utf-8'
```

This thread may help: [How do I check if a string is unicode or ascii?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987327/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-unicode-or-ascii)

Comment: I have already default encoding equal to 'utf-8'. What else can be there?

Comment: Just checking, your`type('César Chávez Day')` is "str"?

Comment: Maybe try this (might be redundant though): `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,1,2], 'col2': [str('César Chávez Day'), str('César Chávez Day'), str('César Chávez Day')]})`

Comment: I understand that is strange, but `type('César Chávez Day') = str` and your second advice also causes the same `unicode erorr`