# difficulty setting up and using Flask_whooshalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, whoosh

I'm currently working on a flask web app with a large database which meant that I had to discard the code I had initially written for WhooshAlchemy.
The first time I tested it I got the following error.

```
   Post.query.whoosh_search('phone').all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_whooshalchemy.py", line 103, in whoosh_search
    if not isinstance(query, unicode):
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

does this have anything to do with python 3  renaming Unicode to str a couple of years ago or is it something else? I tried changing the Unicode into str but that did not seem to fix the problem?
any useful input would be appreciated.

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987327/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-unicode-or-ascii

Comment: The library you're trying to use does not support Python 3: https://github.com/gyllstromk/Flask-WhooshAlchemy/issues/60

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: Flask_whooshalchemy is no longer supported and does not work with python 3.0+.

Solution: you either have to use a custom solution or use Flask m-search which works just fine.

Here's a link to [flask m-search](https://github.com/honmaple/flask-msearch) just in case anybody was facing the same problem.

A quick example would be like the following:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_msearch import Search

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
search = Search()
search.init_app(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ['id', 'username', 'email']
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```