# Encoding of content

Tags: python, encoding, readability, cyrillic

I am writing program, which collects data (title,author,article) from web page with news article. I use Readability Python library. My problem is that content(which programm) of article (if article is written in cyrillic, if article is written in latin it's OK) has such format:
    `{'atricle': u'<div><div class="b-text clearfix">\n<p class="b-     topic__announce">'&#x421';'&#x43E';'&#x440';'&#x43E';'&#x43A'; '&#x43E';'&#x434';'&#x438';'&#x43D'; '&#x43F';'&#x440';'&#x43E';'&#x446';'&#x435';'&#x43D';'&#x442'; '&#x440';'&#x43E';'&#x441';'&#x441';'&#x438';'&#x44F';'&#x43D';'&#x43'....` **without " ' "**
How to make it readable?

Comment: can u use third party tools... if yes.. please verify beautiful soup

Comment: Is it cyrillic as in Unicode or cyrillic as in KOI-8/CP1251/etc?

Comment: I have used this in the past to detect encoding and convert properly to the encoding I expected. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196345/how-to-check-if-a-string-in-python-is-in-ascii#6988354

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python