# Python - remove elements (foreign characters) from list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, unicode, ord

I have a python list with foreign characters that are denoted by some unicode values:

```
python_list = ['to', 'shrink', u'\u7e2e\u3080', u'\u3061\u3062\u3080', 'chijimu', 'tizimu', 'tidimu', 'to', 'continue', u'\u7d9a\u304f', u'\u3064\u3065\u304f', 'tsuzuku', 'tuzuku', 'tuduku', u'\u30ed\u30fc\u30de\u5b57\uff08\u30ed\u30fc\u30de\u3058\uff09\u3068\u306f\u3001\u4eee\u540d\u6587\u5b57\u3092\u30e9\u30c6\u30f3\u6587\u5b57\u306b\u8ee2\u5199\u3059\u308b\u969b\u306e\u898f\u5247\u5168\u822c\uff08\u30ed\u30fc\u30de\u5b57\u8868\u8a18\u6cd5\uff09\u3001\u307e\u305f\u306f\u30e9\u30c6\u30f3\u6587\u5b57\u3067\u8868\u8a18\u3055\u308c\u305f\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e\uff08\u30ed\u30fc\u30de\u5b57\u3064\u3065\u308a\u306e\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e\uff09\u3092\u8868\u3059\u3002']
```

I need to remove all the items with '\u7e2e ' or other similar types . If the item in list contains even 1 ascii letter or word , it shouldn't be excluded. for eg: `'China\u3062'` should be included. I referred to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078816/replace-non-ascii-characters-with-a-single-space) and realized there's something related to values greater than 128. tried different approaches like this one:

```
new_list = [item for item in python_list if ord(item) < 128]
```

but this returns an error:

```
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

**Expected Output:**

```
new_list = ['to', 'shrink','chijimu', 'tizimu', 'tidimu', 'to', 'continue','tsuzuku', 'tuzuku', 'tuduku']
```

How should I go about this one??

Comment: You need the `is_ascii` function, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196345/how-to-check-if-a-string-in-python-is-in-ascii)

Comment: TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to keep all words that have at least one ascii letter in them then the code below will do this

```
from string import ascii_letters, punctuation

python_list = ['to', 'shrink', u'\u7e2e\u3080', u'\u3061\u3062\u3080', 
               'chijimu','china,', 'tizimu', 'tidimu', 'to', 'continue', 
               u'\u7d9a\u304f', u'\u3064\u3065\u304f', 'tsuzuku', 'tuzuku', 'tuduku', u'china\u3061']

allowed = set(ascii_letters)

output = [word for word in python_list if any(letter in allowed for letter in word)]
print(output)
# ['to',
#  'shrink',
#  'chijimu',
#  'china,',
#  'tizimu',
#  'tidimu',
#  'to',
#  'continue'
#  'tsuzuku',
#  'tuzuku',
#  'tuduku',
#  'china?']
```

This will iterate through each letter of each word and if a single letter is also contained in `allowed` then it will add the word to your `output` list.

Answer (score 2):

You can approach like this, as you want to keep the strings and remove the unicodes,

```
new_list = [item for item in python_list if isinstance(item, str)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
import string
python_list = ['to', 'shrink', u'\u7e2e\u3080', u'\u3061\u3062\u3080', 'chijimu', 'tizimu', 'tidimu', 'to', 'continue', u'\u7d9a\u304f', u'\u3064\u3065\u304f', 'tsuzuku', 'tuzuku', 'tuduku', u'\u30ed\u30fc\u30de\u5b57\uff08\u30ed\u30fc\u30de\u3058\uff09\u3068\u306f\u3001\u4eee\u540d\u6587\u5b57\u3092\u30e9\u30c6\u30f3\u6587\u5b57\u306b\u8ee2\u5199\u3059\u308b\u969b\u306e\u898f\u5247\u5168\u822c\uff08\u30ed\u30fc\u30de\u5b57\u8868\u8a18\u6cd5\uff09\u3001\u307e\u305f\u306f\u30e9\u30c6\u30f3\u6587\u5b57\u3067\u8868\u8a18\u3055\u308c\u305f\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e\uff08\u30ed\u30fc\u30de\u5b57\u3064\u3065\u308a\u306e\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e\uff09\u3092\u8868\u3059\u3002']
filtered = [s for s in python_list if all(c in string.ascii_letters for c in s)]
print(filtered)
```

Output:

```
['to', 'shrink', 'chijimu', 'tizimu', 'tidimu', 'to', 'continue', 'tsuzuku', 'tuzuku', 'tuduku']
```

Comment: this approach is a bit slower than the answer by salman . Could you give an example of any case where your answer will work and the first one won't?? or are they fully similar?

Comment: It's a bit odd that your ASCII strings are byte strings and your foreign strings are Unicode.  I didn't notice that at first, but why would there be a mix?  Normally a Unicode-aware program will convert all text to Unicode for processing.  So this answer would work where all the strings are Unicode and the other would not.

Comment: thanks , this works.. as expected even on items like u'there' , whereas the first answer removes all items that have u in them.

Comment: but is it possible to remove only those items that are entirely foreign  in nature?? for eg , with ur answer , a list item like u'China,' got removed because of the comma. Can this be excluded??

Comment: @Swordy More appropriate solution for your case. In this solution `string.ascii_letters` is nothing but a string. you can add special character to it according to your need. like `string.ascii_letters+','`.

Comment: @Swordy, you could also approve all ASCII characters by using `all(ord(c) < 128 for c in s)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way:

```
new_list=[]
for word in python_list:
    if word.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii','ignore') !='':
        new_list.append(word)
```