# How to check whether a substring are of ascii+latin characters and pad the ascii/latin characters substring with spaces?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, utf-8, ascii

Given a string like this:

> 顺便采买些喜欢的CD和DVD或vcd。

The desired output is:

> 顺便采买些喜欢的 CD 和 DVD 或 vcd 。

I've tried looking through each character and checking whether the character before and after is an ascii, and using the following conditions decide whether I should pad a space:

- Check the "ascii-ness" of the current character
- If the previous character's "ascii-ness" is NOT the same as the current's, left-pad a space

But I've been doing it as such and it looks inefficient:

```
def addSpace(text):
  currIsAscii = None; prevIsAscii = None; newsentence = ""
  for i in text:
    try:
      i.decode('ascii')
      currIsAscii = True
    except:
      currIsAscii = False
    if prevIsAscii != currIsAscii:
      newsentence+=" "
      newsentence+=i
    else:
      newsentence+=i
    prevIsAscii = currIsAscii
    while "  " in newsentence:
      newsentence = newsentence.replace("  ", " ")
  return newsentence.strip()
```

This code works in Python2 but, the `i.decode('ascii')` part is not a Python2 and Python3 compatible solution, I've seen [How to check if a string in Python is in ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196345/how-to-check-if-a-string-in-python-is-in-ascii) but there's no solution for both Python 2 AND 3.

Is there a way to check ascii-ness of character such that it works on both Python 2 and 3?

Other than looping through each character? Is there another way to pad space of at the start and end of an ascii substring?

---

Another quirk with the code above is that it doesn't handle codepoints beyond `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, e.g. when the word "Café。" -> "Caf é。", the desired output would be "Café 。"

Try this sentence:

```
s= u"顺便采买些喜欢的CD和DVD或Café。"
```

(For some reason I can't put the desired output since SO thinks it's spam, so I'll just verbally describe. The whole substring "Café" should be padded, not separated into 2 substrings.

The detection of the substring needs to include accented latin characters.

Comment: Shouldn't you try to _encode_ to ascii? Is text a unicode string?

Comment: It's usually a unicode string that contains ascii substrings. And knowing where it's ascii and the start and end points of the offset is needed to pad the space.

Comment: Note that accented latin characters _aren't ASCII_.

Comment: Noted. They are a different codepoint from `latin-1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python3

```
import re
s= "顺便采买些喜欢的CD和DVD或Café。"
re.sub("([A-Za-z0-9À-Öà-ÿ]+)"," \\1 ",s)
```

[out]:

```
顺便采买些喜欢的 CD 和 DVD 或 Café 。
```

regex: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

pip install regex

```
import regex
regex.sub("(\p{Latin}+)"," \\1 ",s)
```

Comment: Thanks! Stackoverflow doesn't use the triple ``` flavored markdown =)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) functionality in the regex module to split your query string where a letter in range `a-z` or `A-Z` if found and later join all the split elements with space to get the desired results as:

```
import re
s = u"顺便采买些喜欢的CD和DVD或vcd"
print " ".join(re.split(r"([a-zA-Z]+)", s))
```