# How to encode only the required headers in a Mime mail?

Tags: python, email, encoding

I'm creating an email using Python's `email` package (which is awesome!!).

I found out that it's better to encode the headers that have some weird chars in them (accents, etc), like the subject, using [email.Header](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.header.html).

To do so, I'm doing the following, which is quite easy:

```
Header(value, 'UTF-8').encode()
```

It works great, but it also encode the fields that doesn't necessary require an encoding, lik

```
X-Mailer: My Service
```

that becomes

```
X-Mailer: =?utf-8?q?My_Service?=
```

I find it pretty useless in that case.

So my question: **Is there a way to encode headers only when it will be useful?**

I thought about playing with `value.encode/decode()` with a try/except, and call the `Header().encode()` function in the except, but I'm hoping there is a cleaner way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's my best approach so far.

It's to try to decode the string using `ascii` charset. If it fails, we encode it using `Header.encode()`, otherwise, we leave it as is:

```
def encode_header(value):
    try:
        value.decode('ascii')
        return value
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return Header(value, 'UTF-8').encode()
```

I came to this solution thanks to this post: [How to check if a string in Python is in ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196345/how-to-check-if-a-string-in-python-is-in-ascii)