# Check if any (all) character of a string is in a given range

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, performance, unicode

I have a string containing unicode symbols (cyrillic):

```
myString1 = 'Австрия'
myString2 = 'AustriЯ'
```

I want to check if all the elements in the string are English (ASCII).
Now I'm using a loop:

```
for char in myString1:
    if ord(s) not in range(65,91):
         break
```

So if I find the first non-English element I break the loop. But for the given example you can see the string can contain a lot of English symbols and unicode at the end. In this way I will check the whole string. Furthermore, If all the string is in English I still check every char.

**Is there any more efficient way to do this?** I'm thinking about something like:

```
if any(myString[:]) is not in range(65,91)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a string in Python is in ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196345/how-to-check-if-a-string-in-python-is-in-ascii)

Comment: Hmm, `range(65,91)` is quite small: only uppercase letters! `'Austria`' would be rejected because it contains lower case letter and `ord('a')` is already 97. Not even speaking of punctuations and digits which are indeed in ASCII charset. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @SergeBallesta you are right. Actually I use two intervals: `range(65,91)` and `range(48,58)`. So I use double condition in `if` statement.

Comment: Shouldn't the "any" in the title be "all"?

Comment: Would your strings _only_ have letters or could there be spaces and periods too?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ they can contain anything. Digits, punctuation, spaces and unicode

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Ah, so none of these answers, nor your original solution would work, unless you account for them all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can speed up the check by using a `set` (`O(1)` contains check), especially if you are checking multiple strings for the same range since the initial set creation requires one iteration as well. You can then use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) for the early-breaking iteration pattern which fits better than [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) here:

```
import string

ascii = set(string.ascii_uppercase)
ascii_all = set(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase)

if all(x in ascii for x in my_string1):
    # my_string1 is all ascii
```

Of course, any `all` construct can be transformed to an `any` via [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
if not any(x not in ascii for x in my_string1):
    # my_string1 is all ascii
```

### Update:

One good pure set based approach not requiring a complete iteration as pointed out by [Artyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5754656/artyer):

```
if ascii.issuperset(my_string1):
    # my_string1 is all ascii
```

Comment: That's a clever solution, I like it!

Comment: Nice and elegant. +1

Comment: Interesting solution. Can you give me one more advice: what if I need not only ascii_uppercase, but all the ascii characters? Can I use just `(string.ascii)'?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam I added that option: you have to combine `ascii_lowercase` and `ascii_uppercase`

Comment: Or we can use `ascii_letters` :) Thank you! I have two more inteteresting questions: How do you think - which method your or https://stackoverflow.com/a/47976402/4960953 would be faster? And second one: what do you think about this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/196391/4960953

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Algorithmically, my solution should be better because [Daniel Sanchez'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695172/daniel-sanchez) set conversion of the string will always iterate the entire string while mine will break on the first non-ascii char. Whether this truly matters or the C-optimization of the set operations prevails depends a lot on your data, I guess.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Why not get the best of both? `ascii = set(string.ascii_letters); if ascii.issuperset(my_string):`

Comment: @Artyer Very good point and rather consequent given the discussion :) I added that.

Answer (score 2):

Another way just as @schwobaseggl suggest but using full set methods:

```
import string
ascii = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase
if set(my_string).issubset(ascii):
    #myString is ascii
```

Comment: Should be faster: `set(my_string).issubset(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase)`

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to avoid iterating.
However, you can certainly make it more efficient by doing `not 65 <= ord(s) <= 91` rather than comparing against a range.

Comment: OP has not tagged Python3, but it should probably be mentioned that checking memership for a `range` should not be noticably slower in Python3 than comparing against ints.

Answer (score 1):

`re` appears to be quite fast:

```
import re

# to check whether any outside ranges (->MatchObject) / all in ranges (->None)
nonletter = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]').search

# to check whether any in ranges (->MatchObject) / all outside ranges (->None)
letter = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]').search

bool(nonletter(myString1))
# True

bool(nonletter(myString2))
# True

bool(nonletter(myString2[:-1]))
# False
```

Benchmarks for OP's two examples and a positive one (set is @schwobaseggl setset is @DanielSanchez):

```
Австрия
re               0.48832818 ± 0.09022105 µs
set              0.58745548 ± 0.01759877 µs
setset           0.81759223 ± 0.03595184 µs
AustriЯ
re               0.51960442 ± 0.01881561 µs
set              1.03043942 ± 0.02453405 µs
setset           0.54060076 ± 0.01505265 µs
tralala
re               0.27832978 ± 0.01462306 µs
set              0.88285526 ± 0.03792728 µs
setset           0.43238688 ± 0.01847240 µs
```

Benchmark code:

```
import types
from timeit import timeit
import re
import string
import numpy as np

def mnsd(trials):
    return '{:1.8f} \u00b1 {:10.8f} \u00b5s'.format(np.mean(trials), np.std(trials))

nonletter = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]').search
letterset = set(string.ascii_letters)

def f_re(stri):
    return not nonletter(stri)

def f_set(stri):
    return all(x in letterset for x in stri)

def f_setset(stri):
    return set(stri).issubset(letterset)

for stri in ('Австрия', 'AustriЯ', 'tralala'):
    ref = f_re(stri)
    print(stri)
    for name, func in list(globals().items()):
        if not name.startswith('f_') or not isinstance(func, types.FunctionType):
            continue
        try:
            assert ref == func(stri)
            print("{:16s}".format(name[2:]), mnsd([timeit(
                'f(stri)', globals={'f':func, 'stri':stri}, number=1000) * 1000 for i in range(1000)]))

        except:
            print("{:16s} apparently failed".format(name[2:]))
```

Comment: Thank you for interesting solution! Thats not obvious that re is faster then another methods!

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam It does similar things like the loop / any / all solutions but my guess is that the looping happens in compiled code, so is faster. From the three examples it seems that constructing the `MatchObject` is responsible for a significant part of the cost, because if there is no match (last example) we are much faster.

Comment: I got it! But I thought regular explessions are slow by themselves and always avoided to use them if it is possible. But now I see I was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non elegant way to accomplish your task.
I'm a beginner, so go ahead and tear this apart.
But it works! :)

```
def english_char(string):
    range_0 = [45, 95]
    range_1 = list(range(65, 90))
    range_2 = list(range(97, 122))
    range_3 = list(range(48,57))
    is_ascii = range_0 + range_1 + range_2 + range_3
    for character in string: 
    if ord(character) not in is_ascii:
            return False
    return True

test_1 = 'Abc123_#'
english_char(test_1)
```