# Remove words in string if it contains \u in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-unicode

I want to remove words in string if it contains **\u** in **python**?

ex:

```py
string ="\uf064thickness cfoutside\uf0d7\uf03a\uf03d TC2019 45TRCMat"
```

The final output should be like this.

```py
"TC2019 45TRCMat"
```

After removing all of the words if it contains \u.

Comment: Aside from the above? What data type is that final output? Is it always the last 2 words?  What if those final strings contain those literals instead of unicode? [ask]

Comment: I'm really new to python. I tried to use regex. But could not able to get above output

Comment: There is no `"\u"` in the string. There is `"\uf064"` for example, but that is the representation for only one unicode character. You can check it with `len("\uf064")`.

Comment: you can read more about split() and replace() ,  those should be in every starting tutorial or documentation of python

Comment: No, it not always last 2 words. its a string that contains huge set of words(that contains words with \u sign and without it). Just want to extract words if it doesn't contain  \u sign

Comment: Remove \u sign from the string is also fine.I tried to use string.replace('\u'," ").But it gives me an error
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape

Comment: us can use `string.split()[-2:]` (output is a list) / `' '.join(string.split()[-2:])`(output is a string) if you want is always the last to elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then looking to remove unicode character go the other way and only allow ascii character:

```
string ="\uf064thickness cfoutside\uf0d7\uf03a\uf03d TC2019 45TRCMat"

def is_ascii(s):
    return all(ord(c) < 128 for c in s)

for s in string.split(" "):
    if is_ascii(s):
        print(s)
```

Reference: [How to check if a string in Python is in ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196345/how-to-check-if-a-string-in-python-is-in-ascii)

Comment: @domahc if this solved your problem accept it as an answer.